# How to split string in php from CSV file and insert to multiple row in database?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

The data in the .csv file looks like this:

```
id | protocol |
1  | SNMP GET |
```

How do I split the data in row protocol (SNMP GET ) in .csv file to store them in difference row in database? It should like this:-

```
id | protocol_type | protocol |
1  |     SNMP      |   GET    |
```

Comment: Will the `protocol` column always have two strings in it?  Or could be one string, or maybe 3 or 4?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just only two str sir.

Comment: @dstudeba thank for correcting my spell.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to come up with a sleek way to simply do one `LOAD DATA` and also extract out the two protocol columns you want, but was unable to do so.  The next best thing might be to do a [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) and then use MySQL's string functions to create the columns you want from the raw data.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE protocol (id, protocol_orig)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Next create the two columns you want:

```
ALTER TABLE protocol ADD protocol_type VARCHAR(55);
ALTER TABLE protocol ADD protocol VARCHAR(10);
```

Now populate the two new protocol columns:

```
UPDATE protocol
    SET protocol_type = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(protocol_orig, ' ', 1), ' ', -1),
        protocol = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(protocol_orig, ' ', 2), ' ', -1);
```

Finally, you can drop the original column `protocol_orig` if you won't need it anymore:

```
ALTER TABLE protocol DROP COLUMN protocol_orig;
```

Here is a demo of the logic used in the `UPDATE` statement.  It is robust to the case where you might only have a protocol type but a missing protocol:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ea59/2)

Answer (score 0):

Let's break things into phases

**1. Grab the data from CSV**

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'sample.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
```

This will retrieve the data in your CSV file. Which `$csv` returns

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] => string(2) "id"
    [1] => string(8) "protocol"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] => string(1) "1"
    [1] => string(8) "SNMP GET"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] => string(1) "2"
    [1] => string(9) "TEST POST"
  }
  [3] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] => string(1) "3"
    [1] => string(7) "ETC LOL"
  }
  [4] => bool(false)
}
```

**2. Iterate the `$csv` into proper readable array.**

```
$res = array();
foreach ($csv as $idx => $data)
{
    // This will skip the header and validate if data is present.
    if ($idx != 0 && $data)
    {
        $rowId = $data[0];
        $protocolType = explode(" ", $data[1])[0]; //Returns 'SNMP'
        $protocol = explode(" ", $data[1])[1]; // Returns 'GET'
        $res[] = array(
            "id" => $rowId, 
            "protocol_type" => $protocolType, 
            "protocol" => $protocol
        );
    }
}
```

In this phase, `$res` returns,

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    'id' => string(1) "1"
    'protocol_type' => string(4) "SNMP"
    'protocol' => string(3) "GET"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    'id' => string(1) "2"
    'protocol_type' => string(4) "TEST"
    'protocol' => string(4) "POST"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    'id' => string(1) "3"
    'protocol_type' => string(3) "ETC"
    'protocol' => string(3) "LOL"
  }
}
```

**3. Store them into your table**

Let's say that you already have the table `protocol` with columns of `id, protocol_type, protocol`.

You can just iterate the array of `$res` and store them into your database. 
***e.g.***

```
foreach ($res as $row)
{
    $sqlCommand = "
        INSERT INTO protocol (id, protocol_type, protocol) 
        VALUES ({$row['id']}, {$row['protocol_type']}, {$row['protocol']})";
}
```